# Terraform validate failing on json policy

Tags: json, validation, terraform

I am trying to create a S3 bucket using a terraform file with custom json policy. I could not find the issue with JSON formation.  Terraform validate is giving an error

"Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 's' looking for beginning of value"
on line

```
    {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999",
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:userId": [
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "999999999999"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Policy Modification",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:cUSTOMpoLICY",
            "s3:cUSTOMpoLICY"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999",
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:userId": [
                    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "999999999999"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

I was able to verify with JSONLINT.com and found it is not an issue with JSON formatting, but something to do with terraform handling the JSON

Answer (score 1):

This is not a actual solution, but I was able to get the policy working, when I moved the JSON policy contents to terraform file by specifying it under

```
    policy = <<POLICY
     {
 {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Explicit deny",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999",
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:userId": [
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "XXXX9999XXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "999999999999"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "Policy Modification",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:cUSTOMpoLICY",
            "s3:cUSTOMpoLICY"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999",
            "arn:xxx-xx-xxx:s3:::s999999999999-9999-99999/*"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotLike": {
                "aws:userId": [
                    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:*",
                    "999999999999"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}
  POLICY

I have used 
Terraform v0.12.9,  + provider.aws v2.63.0
I will try to submit it as a bug in Terraform github